# Build not found when using the command "make" in gentoo linux

Tags: wifi, drivers, compiling, gentoo

so I've cloned this github repository https://github.com/xiangzhai/rt5370
It's a drive for my wifi adapter.
My problem is that whenever I try to use the "make" command, it returns this error

```
/lib/modules/5.3.7-gentoo--g243aa7022-dirty/build No such file or directory
```

This is what I've tried so far

emerge --sync

emerge linux-header

emerge build

No luck, could anyone help me please I've been trying to fix the issue for hours now

Comment: type the command ```which build```, or ```emerge --info | grep build```

Comment: Which build outputted that it hadn't found it

Comment: As for the emerge info grep build it outputted this FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-docompress binpkg-dostrip binpkg-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles ipc-sandbox merge-sync multilib-strict network-sandbox news parallel-fetch pid-sandbox preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync xattr"

Comment: Usually `/lib/modules/{kernel-version}/build` is a symbolic link to the source directory that was used to build those modules.  For example `/lib/modules/5.10.27-gentoo/build -> /usr/src/linux-5.10.27-gentoo/`  It looks like you're missing that build directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my kernel wasn't actually compiled.
Compiling my kernel fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a header issue?

```bsh
ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.7-gentoo--g243aa7022-dirty/ /lib/modules/5.3.7-gentoo--g243aa7022-dirty/build

emerge linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: None worked
I've tried the first one, it said that it didnt match anything

This ./configure && make && sudo make install and this ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install
returned an error saying that ./configure and ./autogen.sh weren't found respectively

Comment: did you modify the file  ***os/linux/config.mk***?      What is the output of                                       ```ls /usr/src/linux-headers* ```

Comment: I haven't edited os/linux/config.mk   when I do the ls thing it outputs ls cannot access  /usr/src/linux-headers* no such file or directory I tried removing the * still the same output

Comment: How about this: ```sudo find / -name linux-headers*```?

Comment: It returned a bunch of results inside /usr/portage/sys-kernel/linux-headers-5.12 and/var/db/pkg/sys-kernel also /var/cache/edb/dep/usr/portage and so on

Comment: Maybe reinstall the headers. Try this ```emerge --ask sys-kernel/linux-headers``` then run the ```find``` command again

Comment: Okay so I reinstalled it and ran the find command again, it outputted a buncha results they look similar to what have been outputted before, if not the same outputs actually. The make command still outputs the build not found error

Comment: Apparently someone told me my kernel is not compiled I didnt really understand what they meant by that